# Black inside of egg shell

Tags: food-safety, eggs

After cracking an egg open, I saw that the inside of the shell is grey/black. It looks like it has been burned.  Is this mold?

Comment: Welcome! Do you have a photo of the egg for us? You can always use the [edit] button to add more details.